# Spring security configuration

Tags: java, spring

I am new to spring boot and wanted to make a simple application with JWT authentication. There is one problem with the response having 401 status when it should have 403 but otherwise everything seems to work as expected.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@EnableMethodSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration {
    private final JwtAuthFilter jwtFilter;
    private final UserDao userDao;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .authorizeHttpRequests(
                        auth -> auth.requestMatchers("/**/auth/**").permitAll()
                                .anyRequest().authenticated())
                .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .addFilterBefore(jwtFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider())
                .sessionManagement(conf -> conf.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS));
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        final DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService());
        authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return authenticationProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration config) throws Exception {
        return config.getAuthenticationManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return new UserDetailsService() {
            @Override
            public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
                return userDao.findUserByEmail(email);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Any tips on how I can improve this or what mistakes I have made not noticed?

Comment: Do you have control over the status code, or are there parameters/configuration options that can affect it? Otherwise is it controlled by an external system? Are you okay with the 401 status or asking how to fix it?

Comment: I am not really ok with it but it doesn't bother me much now (would be nice to fix though). I have no external error handling or other mean that effects the status codes in response. I use @PreAuthorize on endpoints to specify the necessary authority

Answer (score 2):

Suggestion of improvements ...

1. instead of define the UserDetailsService as this @Bean and anonymous class

```
@Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return new UserDetailsService() {
            @Override
            public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
                return userDao.findUserByEmail(email);
            }
        };
    }
```

I suggest define UserDetailsService as this

```
@Service
public class UserDataServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {
    private final UserDao userDao;

    @Autowired
    public UserDataServiceImpl(UserDao userDao) {
        this.userDao = userDao;
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) {
         try{
        return userDao.findUserByEmail(email);
      }catch(){
           log.debug("Can't find user by the email {}, email);
           throw new UsernameNotFoundException("some message");
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, will do that. Btw I don't think you need the @Autowired annotation above constrictor in newer versions of spring boot